# How to input parameters when running bash command with Scala

Tags: scala

Could someone give me an advice how to run command as below in scala ?

```
Process("/usr/bin/mysql -u username -h mydb.host.rds.amazonaws.com -D dbname -p < /data/import.sql").!
```

So far I can't find a workable way to run.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import scala.language.postfixOps
import java.io.File
import scala.sys.process._

Seq("/usr/bin/mysql", "-u", "username", "-h", "mydb.host.rds.amazonaws.com", "-D", "dbname", "-p") #< new File ("/data/import.sql") !
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code samples only. The best answers provide the why and how along with the solution so that users here now and in the future will be able to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to run your command.

```
val p = ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/mysql", "-u", "username", "-h", "mydb.host.rds.amazonaws.com", "-D", "dbname", "-p")
p.setRedirectInput(File("/data/import.sql")
p.start()
```